# Output a ostringstream to file

Tags: c++, string, ostringstream

I currently do this to write the contents of an `ostringstream` to a file:

```
... // -- Loop 1 Start

std::ostringstream osStr;

... // -- Loop 2 Start

    cv::string s(osStr.str());
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    cv::vector<cv::string> subVec;
    do{
        cv::string sub;
        iss >> sub;
        subVec.push_back(sub);
    } while (iss);

    cv::FileStorage fs("subVec.txt", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "subVec" << subVec;
    fs.release();

... // -- Loop 2 End

... // -- Loop 1 End
```

but this overwrites what was previously in the file.

So I moved the `cv::FileStorage fs("subVec.txt", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);` to before the loop, and `fs.release` to after the loop.

```
cv::FileStorage fs("subVec.txt", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

... // -- Loop 1 Start

std::ostringstream osStr;

... // -- Loop 2 Start

    cv::string s(osStr.str());
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    cv::vector<cv::string> subVec;
    do{
        cv::string sub;
        iss >> sub;
        subVec.push_back(sub);
    } while (iss);

    fs << "subVec" << subVec;

... // -- Loop 2 End

... // -- Loop 1 End

fs.release();
```

This worked in a way as it did continuously write to the `.txt`, but was unusable due to Duplicated Keys:

```
%YAML:1.0
subVec:
   - "1"
   - "2"
...
   - "33"
   - "34"
subVec:
   - "1"
   - "3"
...
   - "30"
   - "31"
```

**See how *subVec* is repeated**

I'm looking for a way to save the contents of the `ostringstream` to a file where it doesn't overwrite the contents each time, but is actually readable.

**OpenCV Error: Parsing error (subVec.txt(27): Duplicated key) in cvGetFileNode**

Comment: Why are you embedding pictures of text?

Comment: So you can see the output file. See how it says **"See how subVec is repeated"**. Unless you're referring to the console picture, that just allows me to show the error message in its entirety without having to type it all out.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to make you think with that question. Since that didn't happen, here's what I wanted you to understand: Inserting pictures is stupid, since it costs bandwidth, excludes some people from reading this and is not indexable via search engines. Include the text, it can't be that difficult to cut'n'paste that in here!

Comment: Thats fair enough I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is little response, I'll have to settle with this fix:

```
cv::vector<cv::string> subVec; // -- MOVED
cv::FileStorage fs("subVec.txt", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);

... // -- Loop 1 Start

std::ostringstream osStr;

... // -- Loop 2 Start

    cv::string s(osStr.str());
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    do{
        cv::string sub;
        iss >> sub;
        subVec.push_back(sub);
    } while (iss);

... // -- Loop 2 End

... // -- Loop 1 End

fs << "subVec" << subVec; // -- MOVED
fs.release();
```

Although it does leave me with the issue of `cv::vector<cv::string>` being able to only hold so much.

A fix for this would be good!

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, I open a `std::ofstream m_OutFile` member at class level, open it with `m_OutFile.open(file.c_str(), std::ios::out);` in a constructor call. I also give it a buffer to save hard drive access:

```
m_OutFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(m_CharBuffer,BUFFER_SIZE);
```

and then whenever I want to write to it in a function, I use

```
std::ostringstream oStr;
oStr << "some text and things" << std::ends;
m_OutFile << oStr.str() << std::endl;
```

Works neat for me.